# Mocking Service Bus queue reader

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a function that reads events from a service bus input queue, processes it and writes the result to a service bus output topic. If any error is raised the event ends up on the dead letter queue. I am trying to mock the reading part of service bus queue to assert that the message that in written in topic is what I expect. I also want to assert that in case of any exception ends up on the dead letter queue.

The function in on package dem inside module app

```
def run():
    load_dotenv()
    CONNSTR = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STR']
    QUEUE_NAME = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_NAME']
    TOPIC_NAME = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC_NAME']
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(CONNSTR) as client:
        # max_wait_time specifies how long the receiver should wait with no incoming messages before stopping receipt.
        # Default is None; to receive forever.
        with client.get_queue_receiver(QUEUE_NAME, max_wait_time=60) as receiver:
            for event in receiver:  # ServiceBusReceiver instance is a generator.
                try:
                    res = event_processor(event)
                    with client.get_topic_sender(TOPIC_NAME) as sender:
                        message = ServiceBusMessage(res)
                        sender.send_messages(message)
                    receiver.complete_message(event)
                    print("Message Processed")
                except Exception:
                    traceback.print_exc()
                    receiver.dead_letter_message(event)
```

Despite my mocking efforts I am not able to pass the "for event in receiver". I have the following Testclass with print mocks calls to validate that the code is not working properly:

```
class TestApp:
    @patch("dem.app.ServiceBusClient")
    def test_run(self, MockServiceBusClient):
        sb_client_mock = Mock()
        MockServiceBusClient.from_connection_string.__enter__ = sb_client_mock
        event_list_mock= Mock()
        sb_client_mock.get_queue_receiver.__enter__.__iter__ = iter([event_list_mock])
        app.run()
        print(MockServiceBusClient.mock_calls)
        print(sb_client_mock.mock_calls)
        print(event_list_mock.mock_calls)
        assert False
```

The results is:

```
[call.from_connection_string('Endpoint=sb://myservicebusbus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=UEYDghPiH20xM/G7XOY3QAq0xxvzi165T+ASbM0K3oc='),
 call.from_connection_string().__enter__(),
 call.from_connection_string().__enter__().get_queue_receiver('inputqueue', max_wait_time=60),
 call.from_connection_string().__enter__().get_queue_receiver().__enter__(),
 call.from_connection_string().__enter__().get_queue_receiver().__enter__().__iter__(),
 call.from_connection_string().__enter__().get_queue_receiver().__exit__(None, None, None),
 call.from_connection_string().__exit__(None, None, None)]
[]
[]
```

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong to not reach the code inside the for? Thank you